# Angular2 Material Toolbar auto hide, How?

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

I'd like to auto hide the top md-toolbar when the mouse left the toolbar, and display it when move mouse to the top. How to do that in material2?

Comment: "Mouse to the top", is it good to do that? I mean, is that possible? Because I think top will mean the title bar of your browser not the rendering area

Comment: Sorry, I mean to the top rendering area.

Comment: Something like windows or mac toolbar auto retract